# Resource for Using Logs in Quadratic Sieve Sieving.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, logarithms, prime-factorization, sieve-theory

I am trying to implement the Quadratic Sieve as fast as possible without parallelization or Multiple Polynomial. Through some reading, it seems to me that using logarithms for the sieving step is the fastest way to sieve but I couldn't find a good explanation on it. Can someone please tell me how to do this is in detail or direct me to a paper that explains it pretty well.

Comment: reading pseudocode on wikipedia may help no ?

Comment: There is no pseudocode for logarithm sieving

Comment: nope but the product should be able to be done using it ...